# Variable property

Tags: c#

Is this both the same:

```
private int x;
public int X
{
    get { return x; }
    set { x = value; }
}
```

and

```
public int X
{
    get { return x; }
    set { x = value; }
}
```

I mean is it enough to use the second case or there are special cases I should use the first case?

because I sometimes see codes with first case and sometimes with second case, so i have confused

Comment: Well i think you should use `public int X { get; set; }` :)

Comment: What's the question? Where (in source code) to put the backing store field? If you use a variable you have to declare it (or to use the { get; set; } syntax) otherwise your code won't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd case wont compile - as 'x' (lowercase) isn't defined.

The other option is to use an 'automatic property'

```
public int X {get; set;}
```

All this does, is make the compiler automatically generate a backing field behind the scenes, that you can't directly access, but is mostly the same as your first example.

Answer (score 2):

The second one will not compile because **x** is not declared! if you don't want to have any control on **x** then you can write:

```
public int X { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the second case if `x` doesn't exist in the current definition scope!

If you don't see a declaration of `x` anywhere as in the second case, then it might be a protected field in some parent/base class, although that's *incredibly unlikely*.

Or did you mean to create an [automatic property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) without an explicit backing field? Either this or the first case are the ones that usually occur:

```
public int X { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is second snippet successfully compiled.

Following are conceptually same

```
private int x;
public int X
{
    get { return x; }
    set { x = value; }
}
```

and

```
public int X {get;set;}
```

Why conceptually same : because second statement will create a backing int field with any arbitrary name (not necessarily x)